# What does a symmetric matrix transformation do, geometrically?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some visual intuition behind what exactly a symmetric matrix transformation does. In a $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ vector space, what are they generally?

Comment: Just look at the image of the unit circle.

Comment: Adding to the comment above - the image of the unit circle under the transformation by the symmetric matrix is an ellipse, whose axes point in the directions of the eigenvectors of the symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A real symmetric matrix is always *orthogonally diagonalizable*, meaning that there's a basis for $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of mutually perpendicular eigenvectors of the matrix. Thus you can understand multiplying a column vector by a symmetric matrix geometrically as:

- Express the input vector in a different rectangular coordinate system that depends on the matrix.
- Multiply each coordinate by some constant that depends on which axis in the new coordinate system it corresponds to -- that is, stretch, shrink or flip each axis independently of each other.
- Express the result back in the original coordinate system.